# Loop wont add up a running total of form values

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and I am working on an exercise I found online.
The problem is that the loop does not pick up the values from the form so the running count never gets updated. Any help is appreciated.

Actually one more question, do you have any idea why the values are not getting picked up from the checked input box? The functions are return zero even as I iterate through the loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Configure Your GT Super Sportscar</h1>
<form id="orderform" action="#">
<table border="1">

<tr>

<td><input type="radio" name="manual" checked="checked" id="manual" value="17790.00" />GT Manual</td><td>$17,790.00</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="manual" id="auto" value="18590.00" />GT Automatic</td><td>$18,590.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="manual" id="smanual" value="22455.00" />GT-S Manual</td><td>$22,455.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="manual" id="sshift" value="23155.00"/>GT-S Sportshift</td><td>$23,155.00</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1">

<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="manual" id="combo1" value="1235.00" />Option Combo #1</td><td>$1235.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="manual" id="combo2" value="3354.00" />Option Combo #2
<ul>
<li>Rear Spoiler and Fog Lamps</li>
<li>Keyless Entry</li>
<li>Power Tint and Side Moonroof</li>
<li>Power Windows, Doors, and Cruise Control</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td>$3354.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="manual" id="nocombo" value="0" />No Combo</td><td>$0</td>
</tr>

</table>
<table border="1">

<tr>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="amen" id="cac" value="550.00"/>CD Autochanger</td><td>$550.00</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="amen" id="vss" value="399.00"/>VIP Security System</td><td>$399.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="amen" id="adm" value="295.00"/>Auto Dimming Mirror</td><td>$295.00</td>
</tr>

</table>
<table border="1">

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" /></td><td><input type="button" onclick="showit()" value="Calculate Total" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
* @author Isaac's
*/
function getval(){
var options = document.forms["orderform"].manual;
var optionslength = options.length;
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i &lt; optionslength; i++) {
if (options[i].checked) {
options[i].value += total;
}
return total;
}
}
var result1 = getval();
function getval2(){
var total=0;
var checkboxes = document.forms["orderform"].amen;
for (var i = 0; i &lt; checkboxes.length; i++) {
checkboxes[i].value += total;
}
return total;
}

var result2 = getval2();

function showit(){
var total = parseFloat(result1) + parseFloat(result2)
alert(total);
}

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post your html as well?

Comment: The html automatically renders, hwo do I show just the code?

Comment: Indent code four spaces (the `101010` button). Markdown tips: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has multiple issues.

Here's a [**working jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5usy3/) you can play with.

There's 4 big problems that stop your code from working:

1. In your if loops, when you want to add to the total you write:

   ```
   options[i].value += total;
   ```

   This will act upon `options[i].value`. You want to change `total`, so you should write

   ```
   total += parseFloat(options[i].value);
   ```
2. In `getval()` you return from **inside** the for loop like this:

   ```
   function getval(){
       var options = document.forms["orderform"].manual;
       var optionslength = options.length;
       var total = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i &lt; optionslength; i++) {
           if (options[i].checked) {
               options[i].value += total;
           }
           return total; // <=======   THIS IS STILL INSIDE THE FOR LOOP!!!!!!!!
       }
   }
   ```

   You want total **after** all you calculations, so like this:

   ```
   function getval(){
       var options = document.forms["orderform"].manual;
       var optionslength = options.length;
       var total = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i &lt; optionslength; i++) {
           if (options[i].checked) {
               total += parseFloat(options[i].value);
           }            
       }
       return total; // <===== ALL CALCULATIONS ARE COMPLETED, SO WE CAN RETURN.
   }
   ```
3. Finally in `getval2()`, you forgot to check whether the boxes are checked before adding them to the total. So you always get the same total. You check whether the boxes checked in `getval()`. Use the same method in `getval2()`.
4. When you get `options[i].value` you are getting a string. You should convert these to numbers before adding them to `total`. You only convert to numbers after the totals are returned, by then all sorts of funny concatenations have happened. Look at where I use `parseFloat()` in the snippets above and in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, you never do anything with total, it's always 0.

```
function getval2(){
var total=0;
var checkboxes = document.forms["orderform"].amen;
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
checkboxes[i].value += total;
}
return total;
}
```

Also, one tip that might help you in debugging these types of things (and making your code better in general) is to try using [indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was indented but the formatting was lost. Anyway, you say I am doing nothing with the total variable, so what is the script doing instead. Especially on this line:

checkboxes[i].value += total; 

If it helps any my intention with this code was to loop through and get the value of the selected radio and checkbox.

Comment: @Isaac - You declare and initialize total to 0. Then you loop over checkboxes and add total to checkboxes[i].value. But total is always 0 since you never change it's value anywhere. So what exactly is your intention here? If you are trying to get the checkbox's value, then why are you adding total to it? Just get the value.

Comment: My thinking was that since I had two sets of radio boxes I would loop through all of them and since both sets had differentnamesthat I would just add them(the  respective values) together. Total acts as a placeholder for all the selected values in the form.